# Flutter file_picker package giving null value for all file details

Tags: flutter

I've copied the same code from file_picker package docs, but it keeps giving me a null value for all file details, here is the code I've copied

```
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
   
   print(file.name);
   print(file.bytes);
   print(file.size);
   print(file.extension);
   print(file.path);
}
```

The file name, bytes, size, extension and path are all giving a null value. Anyone know what is the reason for that ?
I've tried to upload a pdf, png, jpg, doc and get the same null value for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the latest version of this:
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

```
  void _openFileExplorer() async {
      File _pickedFile;
      FilePickerResult _filePickerResult;
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      try {
        _filePickerResult = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            type: FileType.any,
            allowedExtensions: (_extension?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
                ? _extension?.replaceAll(' ', '')?.split(',')
                : null);
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
      }
      if (_filePickerResult != null) {
        setState(() {
          _pickedFile = File(_filePickerResult.files.single.path);
        });
      }
      if (!mounted) return;
      {
        Flushbar(
          showProgressIndicator: true,
          progressIndicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          title: 'Status:',
          message: 'File loaded: $_pickedFile',
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        )
          ..show(context);
      }
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but it don't even open the file picker

Comment: Strange, works perfectly here. _pickingType should be FileType.any

Comment: Please send me the full dart file if you can

Comment: I've added the full method

Comment: Still the file explorer doesn't open

Answer (score 1):

you need to set
`withData: true`
if you want to have the file loaded into memory in advance.
Just for someone how is just starting `withData` should be added like this `await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles( withData: true,)`