# Flutter Web: File Picker throws 'Invalid argument(s) (path): Must not be null' error

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Objective: Select a file using file explorer and upload to firebase storage.

Package: file_picker: ^2.1.4

Issue: Throws error: "Invalid argument(s) (path): Must not be null".

The file explorer opens fine and I am able to select a file. However, nothing happens after I select a file. Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
FilePickerResult result;
File uploadfile;

try{
    result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'txt'],
        );
} catch(e) { 
    print(e);
}

if(result != null) {
     
    try{
          uploadfile = File(result.files.single.path);
 
          String filename = basename(uploadfile.path);
 
          StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$path$filename');
 
          final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(uploadfile);
 
          final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete);
 
          if (downloadUrl.error == null){
 
            final String attchurl = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
 
          }
    } catch(e) {
       print(e);
    }
```

I am sure that the code throws error at : `uploadfile = File(result.files.single.path);`

I've tried various suggestions provided in multiple blogs. Even the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061676/flutter-file-picker-package-giving-null-value-for-all-file-details) does not help, I get the same error. See code below:

```
  FilePickerResult _filePickerResult;
  File uploadfile;
  try {
        _filePickerResult = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            type: FileType.custom,
           allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'txt'],);
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
      }

      if (_filePickerResult != null) {
        try{
          uploadfile = File(_filePickerResult.files.single.path);

          print(uploadfile);
        }catch(e){
          print(e);
        }
        
  }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

When I do:

```
print(result);
print(result.files);
print(result.files.single);
print(result.files.single.name);
print(result.files.single.size);
print(result.files.single.path);
```

I get:

```
Instance of 'FilePickerResult'
[Instance of 'PlatformFile']
Instance of 'PlatformFile'
FileName01.xlsx
10
null
```

So essentially, `result.files.single.path` is failing. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use breakpoint to tell te exact line that gives the error?

Comment: uploadfile = File(result.files.single.path);

Comment: Is `result` object completely null? Can you eleborate?

Comment: @easeccy: I've updated the question. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I may have solved this one...

Apparently, `path` is always `null` when using web, according to the [file_picker wiki](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/API#methods).
They recommend to use `bytes` instead to retrieve the file data.

So, following the above instructions and a little bit of tinkering, I was able to upload the file successfully. The modified code now looks like this:

```
FilePickerResult result;

  try{
    result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'txt'],
        );
  } catch(e)
  { print(e);
    }

      if(result != null) {
        try{

          Uint8List uploadfile = result.files.single.bytes;
        
          String filename = basename(result.files.single.name);
          
          fs.Reference storageRef = fs.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$dirpath$filename');
          
          final fs.UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putData(uploadfile);
          
          final fs.TaskSnapshot downloadUrl = await uploadTask;
          
          final String attchurl = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
          
          await AttachmentService(orgid: orgID, orgname: orgName, projid: projID).addattachmentobjs(objType, objID, attchdate, filename, attchurl);
          
      }catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }

      }
```

Basically, I just changed:

```
FilePickerResult uploadfile = File(result.files.single.path);
```

to:

```
Uint8List uploadfile = result.files.single.bytes;
```

and instead of `storageRef.putFile(uploadfile);` , I used `storageRef.putData(uploadfile);`

I did encounter a `MissingPluginException No implementation found for method StorageReference#putData` at `final fs.TaskSnapshot downloadUrl = await uploadTask;`, which I resolved by updating the `firebase_storage` plugin to the latest.

Hope this helps anyone facing similar issue with Flutter Web in future.

Comment: Thank you so much! This had been causing me trouble for days! I had been getting only the console error: "Cannot read property 'Symbol(dartx.contains)' of null"

Comment: @Ramanathan brother i have saved image like this now i want to show image from that url how can i do that?

Comment: What if we still need path of the pickedfile in web